# Angular directive that sets ngIf

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ng-if

I have a few DOM elements in my application that are fairly expensive to load, so I have been using the following pattern to ensure that they aren't loaded until needed:

```
<div ng-if="someCondition || everShown" ng-show="someCondition">
```

Essentially, that makes sure that the element is only added to the DOM once someCondition is true and then it remains there. However, there is a fair bit of repeated logic there and thus I wanted to extract the logic into a directive.

This has been my attempt:

```
export function IfEverShown($parse: angular.IParseService): angular.IDirective {    
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        compile: function(element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery,
                          attributes: angular.IAttributes) {
            if (!attributes["ngShow"]) {
                return;
            }
            element.attr("ng-if", "everShown");

            return {
                pre: function(scope: angular.IScope) {
                    scope["everShown"] = false;
                    attributes.$observe('ngShow', function (expr) {
                        scope.$watch(function () {
                            return $parse(<any> expr)(scope);
                        }, function (value) {
                            if (value) {
                                scope["everShown"] = true;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

The usage would then be:

```
<div ng-show="someCondition" if-ever-shown>
```

However, even though the ng-if value in the DOM changes as expected, Angular simply ignores the changes on it: if there was no previous ng-if, the element is always present in the DOM, and if there was a previous value, it is always observed even after I change it.

How could I get the desired behavior here? Can I get to modify an ngIf from a directive? Otherwise, is there other way to ensure that the element doesn't get added to the DOM until the ng-show condition has been true at least once?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) does not automatically compile directives added to the element during the compile phase. Any newly added directives need to be manually compiled in the link phase:

```
app.directive("myIf", function($compile) {
  return {
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
      tAttrs.$set("ngIf", tAttrs.myIf);
      tAttrs.$set("myIf", null);
      return postLink;
    }
  }
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    $compile(elem)(scope);
  }
});
```

The above example demonstrates a custom directive called `my-if`. It adds an `ng-if` directive during the compile phase and manually compiles it during the link phase.

Notice that it is implemented as a high priority `"terminal"` directive and that it removes the `my-if` attribute so that directives are compiled only once.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/wY2tQlrfFiBvGXIHifiB?p=preview).